# Изменение цвета в меню

Tags: android

Пытаюсь создать тему для приложения в файле style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme">Theme</style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyThemeDark" parent="BaseDark">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark_statusBarColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/dark_colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/dark_itemBackground</item>       <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/dark_navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/dark_colorControlActivated</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/dark_colorButtonNormal</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/dark_colorButtonNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_colorControlHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/dark_colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_textColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dark_textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/dark_editTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BaseDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Все цвета меняются в соответствии с заданными, кроме одного (на рисунке выделен красным овалом). Подскажите - какой атрибут необходимо добавить, чтоб изменить цвет в заголовке меню для подменю.?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]